# excel formula calculation

Tags: excel, latitude-longitude

I have around 200 latitudes and 200 longitudes of different places in my excel sheet which are of the format-

Degree, minute and seconds- for eg: 36°34"44'

This value is stored in a single cell.

I want to convert this value to decimals using the formula, degree+minutes/60+seconds/3600. Please tell me how to apply the same in every cell. The problem is that all degrees, minutes and seconds are in the same cell. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample VBA function that you probably can use:

```
Function Convert_Decimal(Degree_Deg As String) As Double
   Dim degrees As Double
   Dim minutes As Double
   Dim seconds As Double
   ' Set degree to value before "°" of Argument Passed.
   degrees = Val(Left(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1))
   ' Set minutes to the value between the "°" and the "'"
   ' of the text string for the variable Degree_Deg divided by
   ' 60. The Val function converts the text string to a number.
   minutes = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") + 2, _
             InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, _
             "°") - 2)) / 60
    ' Set seconds to the number to the right of "'" that is
    ' converted to a value and then divided by 3600.
    seconds = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") + _
            2, Len(Degree_Deg) - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - 2)) _
            / 3600
   Convert_Decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds
End Function
```

To use, just type `=Convert_Decimal("36°34"44'")`, and you will get result 36.58.

Also, if you are interested, you can have a look at [the other approach](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LatLong.aspx) that takes advantage of time format functions.

Hope these will help.

Some more details on MSDN:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/73023

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213449

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LatLong.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your strings as zero padded (like `06°04"04'`) then use

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))+VALUE(MID(A1,4,2))/60+VALUE(MID(A1,7,2))/3600
```

If not, or uncertain (like `6°4"4'`) then use

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("°",A1)-1)) + 
 VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("°",A1)+1,FIND("""",A1)-FIND("°",A1)-1))/60 + 
 VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("""",A1)+1,FIND("'",A1)-FIND("""",A1)-1))/3600
```